# Poisson Bracket of $\{Q, P\}$ in the original coordinate $(q, p)$

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, phase-space, poisson-brackets

For simplicity, I use $(q,p)$ and $(Q,P)$ instead of $(q_i,p_i)$ and $(Q_i,P_i)$. I know that we should get $\{Q, P\} = 1$ for a canonical transformation $(q,p)\rightarrow(Q,P)$.

But we also know from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_transformation#Direct_approach) that for checking whether a transformation is canonical, we have the direct conditions

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial P}{\partial p} = \frac{\partial q}{\partial Q}\\
\frac{\partial P}{\partial q} = -\frac{\partial p}{\partial Q}, 
\end{equation}

Now if I write $\{Q,P\}_{q,p} = \frac{\partial Q}{\partial q}\frac{\partial P}{\partial p} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial q}\frac{\partial Q}{\partial p}$ and substitute in the above, we get $\{Q,P\}_{q,p} = 2$ instead of 1. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: _But you also know_ from where? Which reference? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic From Wikipedia page for Canonical Transformation, or Goldstein Section 9.4 on Symplectic Approach to Canonical Transformation

Comment: Hint: It is important to pay attention to which variables are kept fixed during a partial differentiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the Poisson bracket
$$
\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial q_k}\frac{\partial P_j}{\partial p_k} -\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial p_k}\frac{\partial P_j}{\partial q_k}
$$
Then use the conditions you propose
$$
\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial q_k}\frac{\partial q_k}{\partial Q_j} +\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial p_k}\frac{\partial p_k}{\partial Q_j}
$$

undo the chain rule

$$
\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial Q_j} = \delta _{ij}
$$

For instance, let $f(x,y)$ and $x(t),y(t)$ then

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}
$$
if you replace $t\rightarrow Q $ in the above example, all you are doing is undoing the application of the differential. You propose the following relation is true
$$
2\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}
$$
which is incorrect!

Comment: If we do this, shouldn’t we get $2\delta_{kk}\frac{\partial Q_i}{\partial Q_j} = 6\delta_{ij}$

Comment: @YiluoLi No, it is simply the chain rule being undone.

Comment: I see. Makes perfect sense now. I have mistaken the double k indices for dummy summation (hence the 2$\delta_{kk}$ factor I got in the previous comment), but in fact every term is just describing how Q change in each “direction” and the rest is chain rule. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By “dummy summation” I mean the usual 1-3, but of course here the repeated indices still mean summation, just over every pair of p and q